# how do i get only one question and related answer in codeigniter way?

Tags: codeigniter

my controller is

```
$data['qna'] = $this->Ivote_model->get_qa();
```

view

```
foreach($qna as $k=>$v){
    echo $v['question']. '<br/>';
        echo '-' .$v['answer'] . '<br/>';
```

model

```
function get_qa(){
    $data = array();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('v_questions.id',1);
    $this->db->from('v_answers');
    $this->db->join('v_questions','v_questions.id = v_answers.question_id');

    $q = $this->db->get();

    if($q->num_rows > 0){
        foreach($q->result_array() as $row){
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    $q->free_result();
    return $data;
}
```

my html page shows

```
What is your favorite food?
-Sushi
What is your favorite food?
-Burgers
What is your favorite food?
-kodo
```

what i want is

```
What is your favorite food?
    -Sushi
    -Burgers
    -koddo
```

please help me how do i achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a couple of things:

```
function get_qa(){
    /* ... */

    if($q->num_rows > 0){
        foreach($q->result_array() as $row){
            // create an associative array of question => answer.
            // that ensures 1-1 mapping.
            if(!isset($data[$row['question']])) $data[$row['question']] = array();
            $data[$row['question']][] = $row['answer'];
        }
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

Then, in the view:

```
 foreach($qna as $k=>$v){
    echo $k. '<br/>';
    foreach( $v as $ans ){ 
        echo '-' .$ans . '<br/>';
    }
 }
```

Comment: could u pls give me a hint for those commented out lines ?

Comment: i did not understand this part // create an associative array of question => answer.
            // that ensures 1-1 mapping.

Comment: Basically, you'll have an array with a bunch of question texts as the keys and the answers as the values: `array( 'question-1-text' => array('ans1','ans2','ans3'), 'question-2-text' => array('ans5','ans6','ans7'));`

Comment: actually i got what i wanted but missing id's of questions and answer in views. Thanks

Comment: Well you could always do `$data[$row['question']][] = $row;` and then `foreach( $v as $row ){ 
        echo '-' .$row['answer' ] . '<br/>';
    }`